# What is httpd.exp used for?

Tags: apache-2.2

In the directory /usr/local/apache2/modules, I see the single file httpd.exp.  What is the purpose of this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

httpd.exp is the export file for Apache and IHS functions, and contains a list of the functions to be exported for use by the modules.